# how can pass data between fragment to adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-bundle

see all post about this and understand in all cases people explain about pass data from adapter to fragment with interface and i use that but my question is how can pass data from fragment to adapter ? and how can pass value of data from those?

this is my adapter :

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    List<jsonContent> jcontent;
    private AdapterCallback callback;
    private String etpass;


    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<jsonContent> jcontent, AdapterCallback callback) {

        this.context=context;
        this.jcontent=jcontent;
        this.callback=callback;

    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       View view ;
        if(i == R.layout.card_row) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        }else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_card, viewGroup, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        if(i == jcontent.size()) {

            viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    jcontent.removeAll(jcontent);
                    callback.MethodCallbacknext();

                }
            });
            viewHolder.buttonprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    jcontent.removeAll(jcontent);
                    callback.MethodCallbackprev();

                }
            });
            viewHolder.go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    etpass=String.valueOf(viewHolder.editText.getText());
                    maghalat f1 = new maghalat ();
                    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                    args1.putString("sag",etpass);
                    f1.setArguments(args1);
                    callback.MethodCallbackgo();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i - 1).pages));


        }
        else {
            viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);
            viewHolder.title.setTypeface(viewHolder.title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return jcontent.size()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == jcontent.size()) ? R.layout.button_card : R.layout.card_row;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title,pages,current;

        private ImageView imageView;

        private Button buttonnext,buttonprev,go;

        private CardView cardView;

        private EditText editText;



        public ViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);



           title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

            buttonnext =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
            buttonprev=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.prev);
            go=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.go);

            editText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_go_page);

            cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cvv);

            pages=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_pages);
            current=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.current);
}
}
}
```

this is my interface :

```
public interface AdapterCallback {
    void MethodCallbackgo();
    void MethodCallbacknext();
    void MethodCallbackprev();
}
```

and this is my fragment :

```
public class maghalat extends Fragment {

    private View myFragmentView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    List<jsonContent> listcontent=new ArrayList<>();

    public int dog=1;
    public String url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maghalat, container, false);


        if(isNetworkConnected()) {
            asyncRun();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "دستگاه شما به اینترنت متصل نیست!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return myFragmentView;
    }
    public void asyncRun(){
       new GetContacts().execute();
    }
    public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);


            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    int id=jsonObj.getInt("pages");


                    JSONArray posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                        jsonContent jsonContent=new jsonContent();

                        jsonContent.title=c.getString("title");

                        //img
                        JSONObject post_img=c.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                        for (int j=0;j<post_img.length();j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject v=post_img.getJSONObject("mom-portfolio-two");
                            jsonContent.imgurl=v.getString("url");
                        }
                        jsonContent.pages=id;
                        listcontent.add(jsonContent);

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pDialog.dismiss();
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            adapter=new DataAdapter(getActivity(), listcontent, new AdapterCallback() {
                @Override
                public void MethodCallbackgo() {
                    String gg;
                    Bundle extras = getArguments();
                    gg = extras.getString("sag");
                    dog= Integer.parseInt(gg);
                    url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                    new GetContacts().execute();
                }

                @Override
                public void MethodCallbacknext() {
                    dog+=1;
                    url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                    new GetContacts().execute();
                }

                @Override
                public void MethodCallbackprev() {
                    if (dog!=1)
                    {
                        dog-=1;
                        url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                        new GetContacts().execute();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"این اولین صفحه است",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }



    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
   }
```

want inside adapter in `go.setOnClickListener` get edit text value and pass it to fragment in `public void MethodCallbackgo() {` but didnt work . and another question is how can send dog variable value inside fragment to adapter ?

Comment: Unclear why the adapter has callbacks. The Fragment should have the next and previous buttons. All adapter needs to do is display the data

Comment: for change value of variable dog in fragment . and your answer not answer of my question

Comment: It's a comment. Not an answer. It's encouraged not to give answers in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it understood correctly, you want to pass data from the callback method call to the interface implementation.

Use parameters

```
void MethodCallbackgo(String data);
```

Pass it back

```
etpass=String.valueOf(viewHolder.editText.getText());
callback.MethodCallbackgo(etpass);
```

Also: suggestion rewrite the AsyncTask to take a URL as a parameter. The URL does not need to be a member variable of your Fragment

```
 @Override
public void MethodCallbackgo(String data) {
    // here you have data 
    //use it ...
    new GetContacts().execute(url); // pass url here, for example 
}
```

---

This does nothing but create a brand new Fragment which is never displayed

```
maghalat f1 = new maghalat ();
Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
args1.putString("sag",etpass);
f1.setArguments(args1);
```

---

Personally, I don't think the adapter should control the page number, though. The Fragment (or just some other class) should contain the previous/next/go button actions and update the adapter accordingly. You've given" too much responsibility" to a class that's only purpose is to display data within a list.

Comment: i attention to your suggestions and thanks . now i wonder ho can pass data from fragment to adapter ?! .its only way i know about  this you have any idea how manage next prev go button end of recycler ?

Comment: so u know how can send value of dog inside fragment to adapter . for ask new question and you answer?

Comment: I might answer, sure. Of course, the simplest solution would be make a `setDog` method in the adapter. Just call that from the Fragment.

Comment: answer this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349558/how-can-pass-value-of-variable-data-inside-fragment-to-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Declare this in your adapter

```
private AdapterCallback mAdaptercallback;
```

Create one method in adapter

```
public void setAdapterCallback(AdapterCallback  adaptercallback){
    this.mAdaptercallback = adaptercallback;
}
```

In your fragment do like this

```
    adapter.setAdapterCallback(new DataAdapter.AdapterCallback() {


          @Override
            public void MethodCallbackgo() {
                String gg;
                Bundle extras = getArguments();
                gg = extras.getString("sag");
                dog= Integer.parseInt(gg);
                url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                new GetContacts().execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void MethodCallbacknext() {
                dog+=1;
                url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                new GetContacts().execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void MethodCallbackprev() {
                if (dog!=1)
                {
                    dog-=1;
                    url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(dog)+"/?json=get_posts";
                    new GetContacts().execute();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"این اولین صفحه است",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: `private AdapterCallback callback;` already exists. It's set in the constructor

Comment: Yes I am only suggesting to pass set callbacks only after the creation of an Adapter.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with declaring as part of the constructor, though.